# why does snprintf() write extra characters?

Tags: c

In my program, I open a file and write "Hello world" in it. I am using snprintf() to populate 'fname' variable. After this I put gdb on a.out and print the string 'fname'. I see that there are lots of extra character in string 'fname' which I did not assign. Where are these extra characters coming from? Could anyone help please?

```
  3 int main(void)
  4 {
  5     FILE *debug_fp = NULL;
  6     char fname[100];
  7
  8     snprintf(fname, 100, "./my_debug_%d", getpid());
  9     debug_fp = fopen(fname, "w");
 10     fprintf(debug_fp, "%s", "Hello world");
 11     return 0;
 12 }
```

gdb output:

```
(gdb) b test.c:10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005be: file test.c, line 10.

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:10
10          fprintf(debug_fp, "%s", "Hello world");
(gdb) p fname
$1 = "./my_debug_16178\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\300\313Ab:\000\000\000\360\005@\000\000\000\000\000\063\004@\000\000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\301\000'\006@", '\000' <repeats 13 times>"\300, \313Ab:\000\000\000\360\005@", '\000' <repeats 13 times>"\260, \343\377\377"
(gdb) q
```

Thank you.

Comment: Debugger shows you all those `100` chars allocated for `fname` array - regardless of whether you assigned something to them or not

Comment: You explicitly told `snprintf` to produce 100 chars into `fname`. It did exactly that.

Comment: @Koshinae No. The size argument in `snprintf` means it will "write **at most** size bytes"

Comment: @neilb please just try `char fname[100] = "foo";` and see the debugger output for that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala. If I do char fname[100] = "foo" then gdb prints only "foo" and no extra characters. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case gdb doesn't care about your 0-terminator in the string and just prints the array, i.e. the full 100 characters in `fname`.

You can also use `printf "%s"` or `p /s` if you want gdb to treat your array as a C-string.

Comment: Or `p (char *)fname` which nicely calls attention to the fact that the reason `p` behaves differently from any function you can call in C is that unlike a C function, it can see an array parameter as an array (the usual "decay" to pointer doesn't happen)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley This is a subtle and important point. In other words since `p (char *)fname` no longer has size information it _has_ to rely on a 0-terminator. Please feel free to edit the answer to add this!

Answer (score 0):

As your question is about seeing a lot of extra characters that you didnt assign, it is always the best practice to initialize the memory (simple variables, arrays or pointers) you define, so that you always see what you expect.

In your case, you could do:

`char fname[100] = {0};`

The response I get from gdb is more predictable thus:

```
(gdb) b 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400610: file st_fname.c, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/gops/data/samples/st_fname.o

Breakpoint 1, main () at st_fname.c:9
9           fprintf(debug_fp, "%s", "Hello world");
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
(gdb) p fname
$1 = "./my_debug_26808", '\000' <repeats 83 times>
(gdb)
```

Now you should see what you expect. Hope it helps.